# How to capture the response based on the Content-Type sent by the server using requests in Python?

Tags: python, http, post, python-requests

I am pretty new to python and learning how to make HTTP request and store the response in a variable.

Below is the similar kind of code snippet that I am trying to make the POST request.

```
import requests
import simplejson as json

api_url = https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/tickets
raw_body = {"searchBy":"city","searchValue":"1","processed":9,"size":47,"filter":{"cityCode":["BA","KE","BE"],"tickets":["BLUE"]}}
raw_header = {"X-Ticket-id": "1234567", "X-Ticket-TimeStamp": "11:01:1212", "X-Ticket-MessageId": "123", 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}

result = requests.post(api_url, headers=json.loads(raw_header), data=raw_body)

#Response Header
response_header_contentType = result.headers['Content-Type'] #---> I am getting response_header_contentType as "text/html; charset=utf-8"

#Trying to get the result in json format
response = result.json() # --> I am getting error at this line. May be because the server is sending the content type as "text/html" and I am trying to capture the json response.
```

Error in console :

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\sam\python-project\v4\makeApiRequest.py", line 45, in make_API_request
    response = result.json()
  File "C:\Users\userName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 898, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\userName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\simplejson\__init__.py", line 525, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\userName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\simplejson\decoder.py", line 370, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\userName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\simplejson\decoder.py", line 400, in raw_decode
    return self.scan_once(s, idx=_w(s, idx).end())
simplejson.errors.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

So, how can I store the response in a variable based on the content-type sent by the server using requests.

Can somebody please help me here. I tried googling too but did not find any helpful documentation on how to capture the response based on the content-type.

Comment: Remove `json.loads` from the call

Comment: I tried removing json.loads from the call, I am still getting the same error

Comment: print(result.text) before  response = result.json() and you can see problem. It's not content-type, it's not json at all. Maybe server sends you error in your query

Answer (score 1):

as you already said your contentType is 'text/html' not 'application/json' that normally means that it can not be decoded as json.

If you look at the documentation 
https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#response-content you can find that there are different ways to decode the body, if you already know you have 'text/html' it makes sense to decode it with `response.text`.

Hence it makes sense to distinquish based on the content type how to decode your data:

```py
if result.headers['Content-Type'] == 'application/json':
   data = result.json()
elif result.headers['Content-Type'] == 'text/html':
   data = result.text
else:
   data = result.raw
```